# How to delete a tab between two columns on many similar lines of text?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a document I'm formatting, it contains 1/2 million lines of text and are basically identical to the example below. I need to delete the the tab in between the two letters, so that this:

```
rs207460002 26  15579   T   A
rs207459997 26  15615   G   C
rs527236190 26  15637   T   C
```

Becomes this:

```
rs207460002 26  15579   TA
rs207459997 26  15615   GC
rs527236190 26  15637   TC
```

Any solutions would be appreciated!

Note: These are 5 TAB columns.

Answer (score 2):

Another `awk` way:

```
awk '{cpy=$NF; NF--; print $0 cpy }' OFS='\t' infile
```

This take a copy of the last field `$NF` into a variable called `cpy` and `NF--` delete the last field from the current input line `$0`; next we are printing the line `$0` followed by `cpy`. The `OFS='\t'` specifies the **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator.

Or `sed`:

```
sed 's/\t\([A-Z]\)$/\1/' infile
```

This capture a matching group on a `\t`ab followed by a single alphabet character in the end of each line with `\1` back-reference to the matching alphabet character only and in replacement part we only keep alphabet and `\t`ab removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 $5 }' input.txt
rs207460002 26  15579   TA
rs207459997 26  15615   GC
rs527236190 26  15637   TC
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer

```
sed -ri "s/([A-Z])\t([A-Z])$/\1\2/" your_file
```

#### Explanation

`-r` - Use regex extended. (Allow some characters in regex to be used without espace sequnce)

`-i` - Keep the changes in the file, do not write them to `stdout`.

`s/([A-Z])\t([A-Z])$/\1\2/` - Match `[capital_letter][TAB_key][capital_letter]` on the end of the line and replace it with matched `[capital_letter][capital_letter]`.

`your_file` - File on which you wish `sed` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed`

```
sed -E 's/([A-Z]{1}).*([A-Z]{1})$/\1\2/' file
```

Explanation:

- `-E` Use regular expressions
- `([A-Z]{1})` Build first group that contains one uppercase letter
- `.*` Match everything inside the groups built
- `([A-Z]{1})` Build second group that contains one uppercase letter
- `$` The match must be at the end of the line
- `\1\2` Substitute with first group followed by the second. This will remove everything inside the two letters.

Answer (score 0):

With the `sed` tool it is trivial:

```
sed -e 's/\t//4' input_file
```

Explanation:

- `\t` is a representation for the `TAB` character. With GNU sed this is ok, OTW use a literal TAB.
- `s/\t//4` this means delete the 4th-occurrence of the TAB character in the current line.

With `Perl` we can use lookarounds:

```
perl -pe 's/\t(?!.*\t)//'  input_file
```

Explanation:

- `-p` makes Perl read on a line-basis + autoprints the lines.
- `s/\t(?!.*\t)//` regex instructs Perl to look for that TAB character to whose right you cannot see another TAB, meaning, it's the last TAB. Then that TAB is deleted.